# hide / reveal function which can be used multiple times in a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```
<div id="my-spoiler">
    <div id="my-spoiler-title" role="button" onclick="(document.getElementById('1').style.display=document.getElementById('1').style.display=='none' ? '' : 'none')">
        Spoiler Title
    </div>
    <div class="my-spoiler-content" id="1" style= "display:none">
        Hidden Content
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to use this multiple times in a post, I need to create unique "id" every time like `id=1`, `id=2`....

Is there any way to call child div without any "id" and achieve the results.

Note: initially the "content" ,is hidden and when user clicks the title then the content is visible.

I don't want to use any plugins for this.

Comment: You can use native HTML checkboxes(hidden) and CSS to do this - or you can use jQuery `.closest` to target the parent of the button - or you can use regular JS. There is no need for an id. What have you tried so far? Without any code - people are going to downvote you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: cabrerahector thanks bro for fix code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var faqToggles = document.querySelectorAll('[rel="faq-toggle"]');

faqToggles.forEach( function(toggle) {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.closest('.faq').classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.faq {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.faq .content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.faq:not(.open) .content {
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

[rel='faq-toggle'] {
  /* this could be a button... maybe should be... */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="faq">

  <header rel="faq-toggle">
    This is the header / teaser etc.
  </header>

  <main class="content">
    This is the full content.
  </main>

</section>
```

OF course - StackOverflow - reorders the code (Backwards) - but something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/t32cqmwx/

Answer (score 1):

There's actually no need to use javascript, this can be done purely with CSS.

1. The "title" is a label for a checkbox (that is hidden).  Clicking on the label toggles the checkbox "checked" property.
2. The input is placed immediately before the content you want to hide / show.
3. The "hidden" content is hidden with css.
4. The [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), combined with the `:checked` pseudo-selector, allows us to style the "hidden" content *specifically when the input is checked*: `input:checked + .spoiler-content`

```css
.spoiler {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.spoiler+.spoiler {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.spoiler input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none !important;
}

.spoiler-content {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

input:checked+.spoiler-content {
  max-height: 1000px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <label class="spoiler-title" for="spoiler-1">
        Spoiler Title
    </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoiler-1">
  <div class="spoiler-content">
    Hidden Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <label class="spoiler-title" for="spoiler-2">
        Spoiler Title #2
    </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoiler-2">
  <div class="spoiler-content">
    Hidden Content #2
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: the "id" of the input and label must match, but this would be trivial to create new "ids" with php and simply injecting them into your markup easily:

```
<?php $spoiler_id = 'spoiler-' . rand(100000,99999999); ?>
```

Since you haven't shared any of your WordPress / PHP code with us, we don't know how you are adding this to your posts, so I can't advise more specifically how to get the ID injected.